# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using weka.jar file in my own java file

Tags: java, classpath, weka, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having problems executing my java program. The code is placed in the file `RunMining.java` and contains multiple `import weka.[..]` lines. The weka library (`weka.jar`) is placed in the same folder.

I compile it:

`$ javac -cp weka.jar RunMining.java`

This creates three files: `RunMining.class, RunMining$1.class, RunMining$classifierType.class`

When i run it: `java -cp weka.jar RunMining` i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RunMining
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RunMining
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My RunMining.java file only contains one class called `RunMining`, which contains the main method. I would prefer not to add the weka.jar file to my `CLASSPATH` since this file will be compiled using a makefile and executed using a script, on different machines.
Any suggestions, to how i can run the compiled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the classpath of your compiled files as follows:

```
java -cp weka.jar;. RunMining
```

This assumes your files are compiled in the root directory which your javac command suggests.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. Note that the `;` should be a `:` eg.

`java -cp weka.jar:. RunMining`
Assuming that the RunMining.class file is in the current directory.

Comment: Right I assumed you where using windows. Did not see you were using a shell. : for unix ; for windows.